# shinyR: call function only when textInput changes but not when textInput field is empty/NA

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to call a function anytime a value from a textInput changes, except when the textInput is empty/non-numerical. Here's what I've tried:

```
if(!is.na(as.numeric(input$input1))){
     f(as.numeric(input$input1))
}

if(!is.null(as.numeric(input$input1))){
     f(as.numeric(input$input1))
}

if(as.numeric(input$input1) && as.numeric(input$input1) > 0){
     f(as.numeric(input$input1))
}
```

I have also tried putting a default value into the function definition:

```
    f <- function(x = .3){
    ...
    }
```

With all of these tries the function is still getting called while the use is in the process of changing the value, so that if I print the value in `f` I get:

```
Value is NA
```

for these function calls that occur when user has deleted the old value but hasn't had time to input a sensible value. So how is it done? How can I call the function once the user has finished inputting?

I also tried adding:

```
if(is.NA(x)){
   x = .3
}
```

to the top of `f` and I am still getting error messages. So this is quite a practical problem, and I've tried many workarounds. **How do I get the function to be called only when the inputs have changed to sensible values? And why are all these checks I've tried failing?**

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide a minimal working example the next time. I think validate in the render* part of your app might do the trick instead of any if statements.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      textInput("text", "text"),
      verbatimTextOutput("text.f")
    )
  ),

  shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {


    output$text.f <- renderPrint({
      validate(need(input$text != "", ""))

      print(Sys.time())
    })
  })
)
```